# Fetching entities in the opposite direction with Doctrine ORM ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: mysql, orm, annotations, doctrine, mapping

What I am trying to accomplish is to return an entity in a ManyToOne relationship and also do the reverse and returns the entities in a OneToMany relationship using Doctrine ORM.

For example if I have two entities `Tree` and `Branch`, it's fairly trivial to use Doctrine mapping to query for a particular tree and get a list of its branches (Where the relationship is one tree -> many branches)

Tree Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Branches", mappedBy="tree_id")
 */
protected $branches;
```

Branch Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Branches", inversedBy="tree")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tree", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $tree;
```

In this example when I query on the TreeController I get back JSON in the format:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "TreeOne"
    "branches": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "BranchOne"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "BranchTwo"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The question is, how do I do the reverse and get a Branch and also its associated Tree, by making a call to the BranchController, so that the result of the call to the API would be:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "BranchOne"
    "tree": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "TreeOne"
        }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was easier than I thought. Because of the mapping, the reverse is as simple as calling setters/getters that map against the Join annotation. So for example:

```
public function setTree(?\Tree $tree = null): self
{
    $this->tree = $tree;

    return $this;
}

public function getTree(): ?Tree
{
    return $this->tree;
}
```

Then in the function where you return data to the front-end client application you simple have to call the above getter:

```
return array_filter([
    'id' => this->getId(),
    'name' => $this->getName(),
    'tree' => $this->getTree()
]);
```

And you will get the data in the format as requested in the question!